# Can't access OAuth2 Youtube API V3

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-javascript-api

i'm trying to view my channel video list and i got this error `invalid_client`.

The OAuth client was not found. that means client id is wrong!.

```
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '############';
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'];`

`googleApiClientReady = function () {
    gapi.auth.init(function () {
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
    });
}

function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
        immediate: true
    }, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        $('.pre-auth').hide();
        $('.post-auth').show();
        loadAPIClientInterfaces();
    } else {
        $('#login-link').click(function () {
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
                scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
                immediate: false
            }, handleAuthResult);
        });
    }
}

function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function () {
        handleAPILoaded();
    });
}
```

A screenshot of the console.google :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be connected or use Oauth2 to view the list of your videos with the YouTube API. You only need an [api key](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register).

A sample example :

```
function googleApiClientReady() {
    var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
        isLoad = true;
    }); 

    request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
        part: id, snippet
        type: 'video',
        order: 'date'
     });
    request.execute(function(response) {
        //list of all your video in the response

    });
}
```

Don't forget to add this file to your index.html and add this following line after :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

From doc [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)